# Apply Class if Child element exist in a loop for mega menu with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a menu structure in Reactjs but having some difficulty in design. There are certain elements which I need to style differently.

So I need to apply different class to parent of those elements.

**Menu Structure Below:**

```
    <div>
<ul>
<li className={this.state.dropdownClass ? "nav-item" : "no-child-dropdown nav-item"}>
    <h5>Text</h5>
    //first loop
    <ul>
    //this is in second loop
    <li className="menuitem" >some text</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li className={this.state.dropdownClass ? "nav-item" : "no-child-dropdown nav-item"}>
<h5>Text</h5>
//first loop
<ul>
//this is in second loop
<li className="menuitem" >some text</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li className={this.state.dropdownClass ? "nav-item" : "no-child-dropdown nav-item"}>
<h5>Text</h5>
//first loop
<ul>
//No data in this but still it will apply the class to parent
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Already tried with below:**

```
var elementAll = document.getElementsByClassName("childrenmenu");
   if (elementAll) {
     this.setState({dropdownClass: true});
}
```

**Sample code for above explanation:**

```
<li className={this.state.dropdownClass ? "no-child-dropdown nav-item ddfull subnav" : "nav-item ddfull subnav"}><a className="nav-link" href={this.props.data.length ? "/" + this.props.params[0] + "-" + this.props.params[1] + (this.props.data && this.props.data[9] && this.props.data[9].link ? this.props.data[9].link : "") : "#"}>{rtl === "en" ? this.state.englishMenu[9] : this.state.arabicMenu[9]}</a>
                                <div className="ddmenu">
                                    <div className="navContent row headRow d-flex justify-content-start">
                                        {this.props && this.props.data && this.props.data.length ? this.props && this.props.data && this.props.data[9] && this.props.data[3].children && this.props.data[9].children.map((data, idx) => {
                                            return <div className="col" key={idx}>
                                                <h5><a href={"/" + this.props.params[0] + "-" + this.props.params[1] + data.link}>{data.name}</a></h5>
                                                <ul className="parentelement">
                                                    {data.children && data.children.length > 0 && data.children.map((data1, idx) => {
                                                        return <li key={idx} className="childrenmenu"><a href={"/" + this.props.params[0] + "-" + this.props.params[1] + data1.link}>{data1.name}</a></li>
                                                    })}
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        }) : ""}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
```

**Note:** The blank UL should be ignored and the class (`no-child-dropdown nav-item`) should not be applied to the parent if it does not have any child element.

**Problem:** It is applying class to all the parent elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to modify the approach you take to generate this menu. You should be deciding what classes to use during the initial creation of the menu, not retroactively inject classes via `DOM manipulation`.

It looks like you're using data from props. It would make sense to consolidate that data into a structure that will be easily manageable

```
menus: [
  { category: "fruit", links: ["apple", "orange", "pineapple"] },
  { category: "animals", links: ["cat ", "dog", "rabbit"] },
  { category: "empty", links: [] }
]
```

Here's a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-wilbur-r4xvy

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menus: [
      { category: "fruit", links: ["apple", "orange", "pineapple"] },
      { category: "animals", links: ["cat ", "dog", "rabbit"] },
      { category: "empty", links: [] }
    ]
  };

  createMenus = () => {
    const { menus } = this.state;

    const sections = menus.map(item => {
      console.log(item.links.length);
      return (
        <li
          className={
            item.links.length > 0 ? "nav-item" : "no-child-dropdown nav-item"
          }
        >
          <h5>{item.category}</h5>
          <ul>
            {item.links.map(link => {
              return <li className="menuitem">{link}</li>;
            })}
          </ul>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return <ul>{sections}</ul>;
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.createMenus()}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

With that sort of data-structure, the styling can be determined in-line with the creation of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the length of items on which you are looping over

```
<li className={loopedItems.length > 0 ? "nav-item" : "no-child-dropdown nav-item"}>
    <ul>
    //this is in loop
    <li className="childrenmenu" >some text</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Please check the edit in the question, there are multiple loop to map over arrays so I am unable to get the length outside the last mapped items. That is the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Here you must be looping on an array or some other DS most probably.
Try to structure your data if not already structure in a way that loop of li items's are having a separate array. for eg:-

```
[{menu: [listItem1, listItem2 ...]}, {menu: [listItem1, listItem2 ...]}]
```

then loop through object to create ul and inside that loop create a list for every array of menu1, menu2 ... key.

for className you can use classnames npm package which will make your code more readable and easier to maintain.

Here is a sample:

```
let megaMenu = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    const [menu] = obj[key];
    const ULClasses = classnames('default-classnames', {
        'nav-items': menu.length,
        'no-child-dropdown nav-item': !menu.length
    })
    const menu = (
        <ul className={ULClasses}>
            {
                menu.length && menu.map(listItem => {
                    <li>{listItem}</li>
                })
            }
        </ul>
    )
    megaMenu.push(menu)
}
return megaMenu;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the looping logic to a method.
After that you can check the results of said method inside your `li` item.
Something like this

```
<li className={this.shouldLoop() > 0 ? "" : ""}>
```

And the method

```
shouldLoop(){
return (this.props && this.props.data && 
        this.props.data.length ? this.props && this.props.data && this.props.data[9] && 
        this.props.data[3].children && this.props.data[9].children)
 }
```

Please note that as it is the code is very verbose and hard to understand.
I would suggest you try and split to smaller methods, this will help you.